# How to move folders from one subsite to another on SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

How to move files from one subsite to another on SharePoint? I need change 15 icons into 9 icons only. There are some folders in these 15 icons, but how to move these folders into the 9 icons without crashing the SharePoint?

I tried to move files from one subsite to another subsite, however, it cannot be dragged and there is no "move button" when i selected the file.

Comment: Icons? It might help if you called things by their real name. If you don't know what it's called, post a screenshot.

Comment: For example, it's Australia icon and there are few folders in this icons.

Comment: Do you mean a library, perhaps?

Comment: I am not sure it is a library as i am just a beginner. But i am sure that those folders are under site content and structure or maybe it can be called as library?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to source library, from the ribbon, open it in Windows Explorer.
2. Go to destination library, from the ribbon, open it in Windows Explorer.
3. Copy & paste the items from source to destination using Windows Explorer

Comment: Is this method can use in any version of sharepoint?

Comment: Opened like this, you see the files as they are, so it's just like copying from a network share to another network share. I think this functionality has been in SharePoint more or less forever, so works across versions.

Comment: I considered this method before but i scare it will crash as it is a company share point cloud. But is this one of a proper to move the file?

Comment: Hi, i have tried the method that you say and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The above mentioned windows explorer approach will work.

Please keep in mind that:

- open SharePoint using IE11 (the explorer view is not available in Chrome, Edge, FF, ..)
- You will lose custom metadata from the source
- Permission settings from the source are lost
- The copied items will also get a new modification date.
- The data will traverse the network 2x: first from source to your computer and then from your computer to the target. So moving large data volumes might take some time.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. As i was told that when i edit anything on share point must be using Internet Explorer, then view the updated in Chrome or Firefox. So, is there any way to avoid the problems that you mentioned?

Comment: No, the "problems" are inherent to using explorer view. It just wanted to make this clear before you started using this solution. If the data volume is not too high (e.g. not 10's of GB's) I would try the suggestion from Jussi. Open 2 IE windows, in one window open the source with explorer view and in the other window open the target with explorer view. Then simple copy/paste the content. If all has been copied to the target then delete the items in the source.

Comment: Noted! Now i be more understanding about sharepoint. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Noted! Thank you for your explanation. This make me to be more understand on share point.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what version or license you are using. In SharePoint 2010 in a site collection with the publishing infrastructure enabled, you can use the Content and Structure tool to move documents between libraries of different sub sites.

All metadata (author, created date, modified date) will stay intact, but custom columns will depend on what is defined for that content type in the target library.

You need to have sufficient permissions to access that tool via Site Actions > Site Settings > Content and Structure.

Comment: Sorry that i only know it is share point online and it is used for company. I have the administration right to edit anything in the share point but i cannot move files from one subsite to another one. I try to copy and paste but it is still cannot.

Comment: Add on again that i moved the file using content and structure tool but it cannot work. I can do anything on the Share Point but except for moving the file.